# flask-sqlalchemy want filter filter nothing

Tags: flask-sqlalchemy

I am using the like function in flask-sqlalchemy, the code is as following:

```
Customer.query.filter(Customer.username.like("%"+name+"%")).all()
```

Customer is the table'name and username is its attribute, name is a variable. I want the code have the same result as following when name is None.

```
Customer.query.all()
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can do your query using sqlalchemy `is_(None)` and `isnot(None)` (also valids with Boolean)

```
Customer.query.filter(Customer.username.is_(None)).all()
```

careful, `is_()` has an underscore to differentiate from the python `is`